# Social norms and Ethics (also called moral philosophy)

Tags: ethics

Do discussions over social norms belong to Ethics (also called moral philosophy)?

I have in mind examples like

- "manliness" (or what we might call gender identity)
- the tolerance or not on homosexuality
- polygamy vs monogamy
- the obligation or not for filial piety

Comment: Pick one? You've got a "grab bag" of topics that have lots of different aspects.

Comment: @BobaFit Well, if I had to pick one on which to focus the question, I would choose manliness, the question of gender identity

Comment: what is gender?

Comment: This question is really, really important. I hope someone answers it ASAP.

Comment: I wonder if you are not a native speaker of English. "Manliness" refers to the traditionally expected behavior of men. "Gender identity" is a political term of art that refers to internal psychological states. They aren't particularly related.

Comment: Maybe "pick one" in your question? There's that link there labeled "Edit."

Comment: If the focus of such discussion is on the moral rightness or wrongness, then it would be ethics. But if the focus is on purely mind or society, then it may be philosophy of mind, sociology, or even psychology.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, questions about gender equalities, polygamy etc can all be viewed from the perspective of ethics. If you spend a few minutes with a search engine, you can find scholarly articles from many philosophers considering the ethical aspects of topics such as gender identity, gay rights and so on.